# Erro ao atualizar dado com condição

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou tentando rodar esse update mas ele so atualiza a coluna "valor" se a coluna  "desconto" for diferente de 0.00. Se ela for 0.00 ele entre na segunda condição do IF e coloca em valor o valor dele mesmo. Se for diferente ele faz o calculo valor_original - desconto.
Alguem pode me ajudar a entender por que isso está ocorrendo?

```
UPDATE pagamento 
SET 
valor = IF(caminho = '2',valor_original - desconto, valor)
WHERE
codigo = 5
```

Comment: X - 0 = X ... qual o problema ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pela sua descrição não existe problema com seu código, e sim uma certa confusão no entendimento.
Sua validação diz `valor` deve ser atualizado com o valor dele mesmo caso `caminho` seja igual a 2; é possível que no caso em que você testou, o `caminho` seja sim igual a 2.
Além disso, caso `valor` seja (em condições normais) igual ao `valor_original - desconto`, quando o desconto for de R$0, o valor será igual ao valor original.

Comment: Tens toda razão. Isso é resultado de fazer as coisas com cabeça quente...rsrs